# nodejs built-in assert with async/await function

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, assert

I use built-in nodejs `assert` module. I want to assert the result of the async function.

```js
const assert = require('assert').strict;

async function f() {
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}

(async () => {
  assert.equal(await f(), true);
  assert.equal(await f(), false);
})();
```

If `expected` equals `actual`, it works. But if `expected` does not equal `actual`, I got `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`

```
$ node example.js
(node:153779) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected values to be strictly equal:

true !== false

    at file:///home/matt/tmp/asyncawait/example.js:9:10
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:153779) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:153779) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Is using option `--unhandled-rejections=strict` right solution?

```
$ node -v
v14.5.0
```

(updated 2020-07-19)

If I set `--unhandled-rejections=strict`, I get expected output.

```
$ node --unhandled-rejections=strict example.js
internal/process/promises.js:213
        triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
        ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Expected values to be strictly equal:

true !== false

    at /home/matt/tmp/asyncawait/example.js:9:10 {
  generatedMessage: true,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: true,
  expected: false,
  operator: 'strictEqual'
}
```

Comment: you need catch it (try/catch), what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Looks like a consequence of using an async IIFE to allow the use of `await`. Try performing the asserts using `f().then(....)` syntax and no IIFE. If you still get the warning, then chain `.catch()`.

Answer (score 0):

`assert.equal` throws an error if the equality test fails. So in the case you're comparing `expected` to be not equal to `actual`, you should use `assert.notEqual`.

```js
const assert = require('assert').strict;

async function f() {
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}

(async () => {
  assert.equal(await f(), true);
  assert.notEqual(await f(), false);
})();
```

Comment: > assert.equal throws an error if the equality test fails. 

Thanks! I got it. In this case, I will handle error by myself.